# Bounded function is Riemann-Integrable if and only if its upper and lower integrals are equal

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, measure-theory, riemann-integration

I was looking at this proof from my measure theory class but specifically im having trouble understanding the $\Leftarrow$ part, that is, proving that for a bounded function $f:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ if
$\mathcal{U}(f)=\mathcal{L}(f)$ then it is Riemann-Integrable, where $\mathcal{U}$ and $\mathcal{L}$ are the upper and lower integrals, respectively. I would appreciate if someone could explain this part of the proof.

Comment: What is your definition of Riemann integral? Because the _usual_ definition is precisely what you are trying to prove.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by the _usual_ definition?

Comment: "$f$ is integrable if $U(f) = L(f)$ and then we define $\int f = U(f) = L(f).$"

Comment: The definition i'm referring to is the one using Riemann sums.

Comment: Propose $L(f) = U(f)$ to be the value of the integral, you always will have $L(f, P) \leq S(f, P, \tau) \leq U(f, P)$ and the two extremes in this inequalities can be arbitrarily close to $U(f)$ and $L(f).$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following $$\mathcal L(f)=\lim_{\|P\| \to 0} \mathcal L(f,P)$$ and $$\mathcal U(f)=\lim_{\|P\| \to 0} \mathcal U(f,P)$$ which are valid in any case.

Then, if $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $\delta_1>0$ such that $$\mathcal L(f,P)>\mathcal L(f)-\varepsilon$$ if $\|P\|<\delta_1$

and there exists $\delta_2>0$ such that $$\mathcal U(f,P)<\mathcal U(f)+\varepsilon$$ if $\|P\|<\delta_2$ .

Let $\delta=\min\{\delta_1,\delta_2 \}$ .

If $T$ is any set of tags of $P\,$, you have $$\mathcal L(P)-\varepsilon < \mathcal R(f,P,T) < \mathcal U(P)+\varepsilon$$

if $\|P\|<\delta$ because $$\mathcal L(f,P)\le \mathcal R(f,P,T)\le \mathcal U(f,P)$$ So you are done.

Just tell me if you already knew the limits at the start.

Comment: How are you defining $\mathcal{U}(f,P)$ and $\mathcal{L}(f,P)$?, assuming you are using these symbols as the upper and lower integrals. Because in my class we defined them as 
$$\mathcal{L}(f)=\sup\{L(f,P) : P \text{ is a partition of } [a,b]\}$$  $$\mathcal{U}(f)=\inf\{U(f,P) : P \text{ is a partition of } [a,b]\}$$

where $U$ and $L$ are the upper and lower **sums**.

Comment: I think what I should've asked is if $\mathcal{U}(f,P)$ is an integral or a sum, in your notation.

Comment: @RaiBd $\;$ $\mathcal U(f,P)$ is a sum of course in my notation. I just wonder why they didn't use simply $U(f)$ instead of $\mathcal U(f)$.

Comment: @RaiBd $\;$ The equalities at the beginning of my answer are a theorem. I didn't prove just because it's well known.